# Manually duplicate a file in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm coding a local plugin in Moodle and I'm trying to copy resources from one course to another one manually (not doing a backup and restoring).

I've tried to manually get the resource, the course_module, the context and finally the file from DB, then copying rows and updating the fields that concern to the new course, and also chaning SHA1 from pathnamehash file's table field.

Any ideas or alternatives to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for function create_file_from_storedfile($filerecord, $fileorid), as seen in lib/filestorage/file_storage.php.

This function is (surprisingly) not documented in the [file api](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API) page, but seems to fit the bill. The [examples given on that page](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API#Examples) might help.

Hopefully this helps!